How to create clickable links in comments for navigating to other files, methods, or classes in PyCharm (.py files)
I see there is already support for .md files to have clickable links to internal files
For example:
let say you have a example.env file at project/repository root (awsome-project/example.env)
then I can reference this file using
[example.env](/.env.example)
or if there is external link I can do:
[Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/).
However, I want to reference to a specific line of code in .py files for easy navigation.
For example, If I have a class:
class ServiceCallback():

    def handle_success(self, instance):
        ...
        ...
        ... # I want to link/reference to this line

        instance.send_success_notification()

I need to refer to specific line of code in that class/method. Is this possible ?

After researching, I found some useful posts related to this feature, i.e. this one  and this one and found that there is no native support for such feature in pycharm-professional IDE but can be achieved using a pycharm plugin and this does pretty much what I need. I'll post the solution here maybe it helps someone else.
You will need to install this plugin and restart IDE.
Let say you want to navigate to that specific line of code from a file1.py to another file2.py file in your project, you can use following notation to enable clickable link you can also create custom tag to navigate or point to exact line of code:
class SomeClass():

   def some_method(self):
       ...
       ...
       # refer to [[ServiceCallback#handle_success]] or see: [[CustomTag]]
       ... 

In other .py file I can do:
class ServiceCallback():

    def handle_success(self, instance):
        ...
        ...
        ... 
        # #[[CustomTag]]

        instance.send_success_notification()

